# How do I construct a Set with an Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, set, ecmascript-6

I am playing with `Set` in Node.JS v0.11.3 and the `--harmony` flag. The API works fine, I can `add`, `remove`, `clear`, etc. I have however not been able to initialise a set with an array. I have tried (as prompted by [the MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set))

```
var mySet = new Set([1, 1, 2]);
```

How can I convert an array to a set? Is MDN outdated? Has Node.JS simply not implemented the feature?

Comment: looking at the code won't tell ?

Comment: For newcomers, node v12 does support this.

Comment: Cant seem to get this working in Node V4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [v8 implementation](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/collection.js#45) of the `Set` constructor does not yet support the `iterator` and `comparator` arguments mentioned in §15.16.1.1 of the [current draft of the Harmony specification](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/lib/exe/fetch.php?id=harmony%3Aspecification_drafts&cache=cache&media=harmony%3aworking_draft_ecma-262_edition_6_05-14-13-nomarkup.pdf), and node uses v8 as its JavaScript interpreter.

As a band-aid, you can use the [simplesets package](https://npmjs.org/package/simplesets).

Answer (score 3):

Works fine in v8 now using an array supplied to a constructor. I'm using node v6.2.0 (v8 version 5.0.71.47).

```
> let mySet = new Set([1,2,3]);
undefined
> mySet;
Set { 1, 2, 3 }

> for ( let key of mySet ) { console.log(key) }
1
2
3
undefined

> mySet.size
3
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I have read it is my understanding that the implementation of this is new and experimental. Some things might not work properly. Also I have noted many instances where new features did not behave as expected until after a period of maturing. It would be best to avoid this and simply add them manually if functionally is your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

- https://github.com/PeterScott/simplesets-nodejs

Sample session:

```
> var sets = require('simplesets')
undefined
> var mySet = new sets.Set([1, 1, 2]);
undefined
> mySet
{ _items: [ 1, 2 ] }
> mySet.size()
2
```